# Will using dblinq to SQLite in a Windows Store app pass store validation?

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, microsoft-metro, dblinq, sqlite-net

I've been trying to figure out how to get a decent LINQ to *something* working for ORM database access in a Windows Store app.
All I've found is SQLite and the sqlite-net NuGet package.  The latter sucks a bit, as I don't get any .dbml like structure which resolves relationships and provides navigation properties for easy querying (no manual joins needed then).

I was wondering:

1. Does dblinq in comnbination with SQLite offer this?
2. Will using this pass Windows Store validation?

Thank you !

Update: Some links I used in my research:

- The famous Tim Heuer post on SQLite and Windows 8: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx
- DBlinq: http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/
- sqlite-net: http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-net/
- Interesting discussion stating ADO.NET is not possible: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/e9cdd75d-03e4-4577-988e-4c02a52e3f50

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905084/can-i-use-entity-framework-or-linq-to-sql-with-windows-8-metro-style-apps) also deals with the same problems, giving more alternatives to using DBlinq.

Comment: I've reconsidered sqlite-net for not having the navigation properties, but it gets worse as it does not have a LINQ "select" implementation.  To create any maintainable and efficient code, at least you should be able to get a full LINQ implementation for SQLite right?

Comment: An interesting discussion on MSDN forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/52c5459d-66b9-4706-b605-9a323abefd5b

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with dblinq but by looking at the sqlite tests in the project, it seems the library is offering what you're looking for, i.e. navigation properties for relationships between different tables.

Since dblinq is a .NET library, using it shouldn't make the store validation fail. There is another problem though: you can't use such a .NET library in a Windows Store application, only Windows Store class libraries and portable class libraries are allowed. Since the source for the library is available, you can try compiling it as a Windows Store class library, but I'm afraid there are going to be some classes missing that dblinq is depending on which might make it difficult to port.

Comment: First problem I see is that DBlinq uses System.Data namespace which is not available in Windows Store apps as found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193999/winrt-system-data-connect-to-sql)