# System.Data namespace missing from visual studio 2013 for windows blank app template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I have created new blank WP8.1 app from visual studio 2013 for windows and trying to test some database tutorials.

When i try to add System.Data, i get an error "type or namespace data does not exists in namespace System" and it's not shown in intelisense. Also, when i try to use some thing from system.data, there is no option to "fix error" by adding required namespace.

[image]

When i create Databound app template, i can use system.data normally..

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried adding the assembly from the "Add References..." dialog? It is usually found in the System.Data.dll assembly.

Comment: It says that all assemblies are already included in project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the screenshot above it looks like you're creating a WinRT template, that's why the System.Data namespace is not present. The DataBound template is Windows Phone Silverlight-based, and it has System.Data.

You can try one of the following:
1. When you create a Blank App, select "Blank App (Windows Phone Silverlight)" 
2. Look at this similar thread with more info: [WinRT System.Data - Connect to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193999/winrt-system-data-connect-to-sql)

Hope that helps! Please let me know!